# How do I set up the environment on Spyder to work with PLAXIS?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I'm currently trying to set up my Spyder on Anaconda to connect with PLAXIS. However, I'm not sure how to do that and couldn't find a step by step guide online.

I've tried to change the Python interpreter to the python.exe in the Bentley folder but an error says "spyder-kernels not installed". I've tried to create another environment and install this spyder-kernels but when I changed the Python interpreter it still didn't work. My guess is that I have to connect the Bentley python.exe and the spyder-kernels somehow. Can anyone please provide some help? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Your guess is right: you need to install Spyder-kernels in the Bently python you mentioned (I don't know what's that, but it seems a specialized Python version). Before telling you how to do that, I just need to know: does that version use conda or pip packages?

Answer (score 0):

You install Plaxis. Plaxis comes within the installation with a Python Interpreter (usually > v3.8.x). And I assume you also have a python interpreter on your own PC.

From here it can work in two ways:

1. You use the Python interpreter that comes with Plaxis.
2. You use your own Python interpreter to connect to Plaxis.

In case nr.1: Make sure you are in your correct working directory for future plaxis scripts. In your IDE, you have to change the Python interpreter to the one that comes with Plaxis, usually found in the C:\ProgramData\Bentley\Geotechnical\PLAXIS Python Distribution V2\python folder. Next you have to connect to the Plaxis API.
Create an empty python file "example.py" in your working directory, then type this:

```
from plxscripting.easy import *
import subprocess, time

PLAXIS_PATH = r'C:\Program Files\Bentley\Geotechnical\PLAXIS 2D CONNECT Edition V22\\Plaxis2DXInput.exe'  # Specify PLAXIS path on server.

PORT_i = 10000  # Define a port number.
PORT_o = 10001

PASSWORD = 'SxDBR<TYKRAX834~'  # Define a password (up to user choice).

subprocess.Popen([PLAXIS_PATH, f'--AppServerPassword={PASSWORD}', f'--AppServerPort={PORT_i}'], shell=False)  # Start the PLAXIS remote scripting service.

time.sleep(5)  # Wait for PLAXIS to boot before sending commands to the scripting service.

# Start the scripting server.
s_i, g_i = new_server('localhost', PORT_i, password=PASSWORD)
s_o, g_o = new_server('localhost', PORT_o, password=PASSWORD)

s_i.new()

g_i.gotostructures()
```

In case nr.2: You have to go to your Plaxis input program then Expert > Python > Configure Python interpreter > Choose your interpreter and install the required components as you will not be otherwise able to use the plxscripting module. After that is just the same as in case 1.